# SoapUI - Service returns no operations

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soapui

The API I am supposed to target uses this WSDL(http://www.gotoworkspace.com/us/paas/s3PaaS.wsdl), though when I test it in SoapUI I receive no operations. Oddly enough when I make a request on my own client I get a 303 response telling me to redirect to the following - http://www.gotoworkspace.com/us/paas/PaaSServer.php

```
Questions:

1. What do you think is going on?

2. What is my endpoint and namespace?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SoapUI is not handling the redirect correctly.

Try using http://www.gotoworkspace.com/us/paas/PaaSServer.php?wsdl for your WSDL instead.